# Split text to columns error VBA 1004 erorr

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split text to columns (column H) but it shows me an error, can someone help me solving it?

```
Sub Prueba():

'Define all variables

Dim i As Double

Dim rg As Range

Dim strDataRange As Range

Dim keyRange_d As Range

Dim keyRange_z As Range

i = 2

'Define last row count
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Insert columns and divide date and hour

'Range("I:I").Insert
Set rg = Range("H1").CurrentRegion

rg.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("H1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True




End Sub
```

••••ˇˇˇˇ

Thanks

[image: Code]

[image: Error]

Comment: `Set rg = Range("H1:H" & last_row  )`

Comment: Hi Scott, I already changed it and it keeps showing me the error, do you know what else can I change?